# Blank view after pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Returning to iOS development after a year break, and its all mayhem.

When executing the 3 lines of code below, i see the screenshot of the emulator below.

I've also attempted to add the LoginForm view controller as the root view controller, as it should, except i also see a blank screen.

As shown in the screenshot of xcode, the naming all matches up. All the constraints are also blue.

I've included a NSLog in the viewDidLoad of the LoginForm, that i have seen log at points, but still nothing is displayed.

What am i missing, or doing wrong? I've got nothing from errors to work with.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginForm"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES ];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is self a navigationcontroller at the first place?

Comment: no, self is being called from within the first ViewController

Comment: From your screen shots its look like you didn't embed in Navigation controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Because your storyboard doesn't seem to be using navigation contoller.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Although @Piyush Patel  does make a good comment about the navigation controller, i feel i may also hit an issue related to this. Regardless, you're answer works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you Have Xib File

```
   Viewcontroller1 *viewController = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] 
   initWithNibName:@"Viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

if you have Storyboard

```
 Viewcontroller1*vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Viewcontroller1"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```